# react native flux pop multiple component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I currently use react native flux inside my application, I want to pop multiple component at the same time:

At this time I do this:

```
Actions.pop();
Actions.pop();
Actions.pop();
```

I don't think this is the better way

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by passing popNum as parameter, that allows you to pop **n** components

For example, if you want to pop 2 components at the same time:

```
Actions.pop({popNum: 2});
```